# Show there is a closed set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)\leq\epsilon$ that does not contain a nonempty open interval.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I am working on the following task:

Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an closed set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)\leq\epsilon$, that does not contain a nonempty open interval.

This is what I have so far: Take $\mathbb{Q}=(q_n|n\in\mathbb{N})$ and define $A:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n)$ with appropiate $r_n>0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure how to contiune from here. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Good job, now let $r_n$ be such that $\sum 2r_n \leq \varepsilon$ and you're done

Comment: Hi @Jakobian , thanks a lot for your answer :) It's a little bit late in the day... Could you please elaborate a little bit more? I am not fully sure how to proceed with your statement.

Comment: Where are you stuck? All the properties you want follow from the choice of $A$ you did

Comment: Just to be sure: Due to our choice of $A$ and $r_n$ we can conclude that $\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)=\lambda^1(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n))$ and since $\lambda^1$ is sub-additive we conclude that $\lambda^1(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n))\leq \sum\lambda^1((q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n))\leq \epsilon$, right? And this closes the proof, do you agree?

Comment: $\lambda^1(\bigcup (q_n-r_n, q_n+r_n))\leq \sum \lambda^1((q_n-r_n, q_n+r_n)) = 2\sum r_n\leq \varepsilon$, yes. All the other properties, $A$ being closed comes from complement being open, and it not containing an interval follows from $A$ being disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the complete proof, thanks to everyone who helped with this:

Look at $\mathbb{Q}=(q_n|n\in\mathbb{N})$. Let's define $A$ as follows $A:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n)$ with $r_n>0$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let's now find a $r_n$ that helps to fulfill the requirements, for this we want: $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}r_n\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
For this we easily find $r_n=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. It now follows: $$\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)=\lambda^1(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n))$$
Since $\lambda^1$ is $\sigma$-subadditive it follows $$\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda^1((q_n-r_n,q_n+r_n))=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(q_n+r_n-q_n+r_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2r_n=\epsilon$$
$A$ is closed as the complement of an open set. $A$ does not contain any nonempty interval since $A\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset$, $A$ is disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}$. With this we have found a closed set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)\leq\epsilon$, that does not contain a nonempty open interval, this conlcudes the proof.